# Mongo db log disabling

Tags: mongodb

I dont want mongodb to log anything in mongod.log . Please let me know how to suppress the same as it is growing in size and occupy lot of space. I have tried with mongo.conf file but it looks there is no option to disable logs

Thanks

Comment: there is no way to completely disable logging - I presume you'd want to know about errors, at least?  If you really don't want any logging you can redirect it to /dev/null (I don't advise it).  Another way of trimming them would be to use "logRotate" frequently and deleting older files only keeping current and maybe one more.

Comment: That is not true at all @OrArbel

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this works or not send logs to /dev/null ?

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  logRotate: reopen
  quiet: true
  #path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
  path: /dev/null
```

or can also add to crontab ( empty file every 30 min )

*/30 * * * * cat /dev/null > /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Comment: `mongod --logpath /dev/null` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable profilling in mongoDB or set a Profiling level .

More here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

Answer (score -3):

1) db.adminCommand({setParameter:1, logLevel:0 })   // from mongo shell, this can be set using config file too

2) disable slow query profiling in config file

3) in config file, set, quiet = true

Comment: Loglevel 0 is the default, i.e. it does not disable the logging